# seaborn scatterplot is plotting more dates than exist in the original data

Tags: python, seaborn

My dataset contains data for 2018. I tried plotting a simple scatterplot, and for some reason seaborn plots from 2000 - 2018. I haven't found a solution for this.

seaborn lineplot works.

Matplotlib scatter also works with no issue.

Code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (7,7), dpi = 200)
sns.scatterplot(x = df["Date"].values,
           y = df["values"].values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: scatter plots work best with two continuous columns and it seems you only have one. If you only want to `plot values` column, you consider `sns.distplot()`

Answer (score 3):

You can manually set the limits of the x axis by using `.set()` on the plot.

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x = df["Date"].values, y = df["values"].values)
ax.set(xlim = ('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1641) on the seaborn issue tracker regarding this topic. The developers say the issue is a [matplolib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) related to the autoscaling of collections.

They recommend to do it in matplotlib instead.