# Create a date scatterplot with seaborn colored by category

Tags: seaborn

I did search through a variety of examples.  Many of these examples feature edge cases where the poster is trying to do something more than a simple plot.  I also looked for a lot of help.

I just want to have a plot where date is on the x-axis, a count is on the y-axis and the dots are colored by category.  In the beginning, I got close but for some reason that plot showed dates before when I wanted it to start.

This post was "Closed" but after some work and using suggestions, the plot
works.  Code working code is below

```
# Plot
# Load libraries
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create sample data set
pen = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
pen['dates'] = pd.date_range(start = '2012-01-01', end = '2013-06-01')[:344]
pen = pen[['dates','flipper_length_mm','sex']].dropna()

# Use a mask to subset obs if needed
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates  
mask = (pen['dates'] >= '2012-04-01')
pen2 = pen.loc[mask]

# Create Plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='dates', y='flipper_length_mm', data=pen2, hue="sex", ax = ax) 

# Limit date range
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963816/seaborn-scatterplot-is-plotting-more-dates-than-exist-in-the-original-data
ax.set(xlim =  ('2012-04-01',  '2013-01-01'))
```

Here is a working plotnine version of the same concept.

```
from plotnine import *
from mizani.breaks import date_breaks
from mizani.formatters import date_format
(
    ggplot(pen, aes(x='dates', y = 'flipper_length_mm', color = 'sex'))
    + geom_point()
    + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks('1 month'))
    + theme(axis_text_x = element_text(rotation = 90, hjust = 1))
    + labs(title = "Penguins")
)
```

Comment: If you want to limit the data range, that is done in pandas, it's not a plot feature. https://stackoverflow.com/q/29370057/7758804 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/28569461/7758804. There are many existing answer on SO for this.

Comment: `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=pen, x='dates', y='flipper_length_mm', hue="sex") `

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  Actually I did limit the dates using Pandas but the plot still started at the same date.  I also verified that the new data set did not contain the old dates.  Not sure what was happening, so I decided to do it with the plot.

Comment: The other option is with `.set_xlim`, as shown in the last duplicate.

Comment: I see this was closed, but I still don't have a working code sample.  This is where I don't like the "closing" questions.  it doesn't solve a person's problem.

Comment: See [code & plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iJLy.png). Selecting the date range and then plotting works without issue.

Comment: I modified the question to remove the date range requirement because just getting a working plot is more important.  Although the plotnine is working.

Comment: `x=` and `y=`, not `x_vars=` nor `y_ravs`. I'm not sure where you're getting those parameters.